# How would I set sampler2D uniforms in OpenGL in a SPIR-V Shader?

Tags: opengl, spir-v

I am compiling this shader with glslangValidator, and am using OpenGL 4.3 Core Profile with the extension GL_ARB_gl_spirv, and using the GLAD webservice to generate function pointers to access the Core OpenGL API, and SDL2 to create the context, if that is of any use.

If I have a fragment shader like so:

```
#version 430 core

//output Fragment Color
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outFragColor;

//Texture coordinates passed from the vertex shader
layout (location = 0) in vec2 inTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D inTexture;

void main()
{
    outFragColor = texture(inTexture, inTexCoord);
}
```

How would I be able to set which texture unit `inTexture` uses?

From what I have read online through documents, I cannot use `glGetUniformLocation` to get the location of this uniform to use in `glUniform1i`, because of the fact I am using SPIR-V, instead of GLSL directly.

What would I need to do to set it in a fashion like `glUniform1i`? Do I need to set the `location` in the layout modifier? The `binding`? I've tried to use Uniform Buffer Objects, but apparently `sampler2D` can only be a uniform.

Comment: You need a layout and binding for the uniform. For example `layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D inTexture;`

Comment: @DhirajWishal After that, how would I edit the ```sampler2D``` from my main program?

Comment: @DhirajWishal Would I just enter ```1``` into ```glUniform```?

Comment: I personally don't have much experience with OpenGL but in Vulkan. So I guess you can get it to work with `glUniform1i` even though i'm not 100% sure about it. From what i do know, its not an easy task to use SPIR-V to work with OpenGL.

Comment: @DhirajWishal It appears to work so far with ```glUniform1i```. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since GLSL 4.20, you have the ability to set the binding point for any [opaque type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Opaque_Type) like samplers from GLSL code directly. This is done through [the `binding` `layout` qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points):

```
layout(binding = #) uniform sampler2D inTexture;
```

The `#` here is whatever binding index you want to use. This is the index you use when binding the texture: `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + #)`. That is, you don't *need* to use `glProgramUniform` to set the uniform's value anymore; you already set it in the shader.

If you want to modify the binding dynamically (and you *shouldn't*), GLSL 4.30 offers the ability to set the location for any non-block `uniform` value via [the `location` `layout` qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location):

```
layout(location = #) uniform sampler2D inTexture;
```

This makes `#` the uniform's location, which you can pass to any `glProgramUniform` call.